# How to identify which column is causing error converting from nvarchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to run this insert into query and I am getting and error converting from varchar to numeric. I would like to know how do I identify which column is causing this error?

Query

```
INSERT INTO [StagingDB].[dbo].[tmpMam6]  
    SELECT
        --gPolicy_Number_Static  
        gPolicy_Number  
       ,gCustomer_Number  
       ,gProductkey  
       ,Policy_Number  
       ,Policy_Line_Active_Flag  
       ,Policy_LIne_Open_Date  
       ,Policy_Line_Inactive_Date  
       ,Policy_Source  
       ,Lead_Source  
       ,Planner_Banker  
       ,Planner_Banker_StaffNumber  
       ,StaffNo  
       ,Sales_Channel  
       ,Policy_System_Status  
       --,Old_Policy_Number  
       ,Submit_Month  
       ,Accept_Month  
       ,Completed_Month  
       ,Lapse_Month  
       ,Surrender_Month  
       ,Reinstate_Month  
       ,Completed_Flag  
       ,Frequency  
       ,Premium  
       ,Sales_Category  
       ,Sales_SubCategory  
       ,HouseName  
       ,Cluster  
       ,segment_key  
       ,Dedupe_static  
       ,Segment_Group  
       ,Sement_Division  
       ,Segment_L1_short_Desc  
       ,Segment_L2_short_Desc  
       ,Segment_L3_short_Desc
       ,Customer_type  
       ,Customer_Gender  
       ,Customer_DOB  
       ,ag_suburb_code  
       ,Micro_Market  
       ,RBB_Region  
       ,RBB_Province  
       ,RBB_Division  
       ,Area_segment  
       ,Product_roll_up  
       ,Category  
       ,Sub_Category  
       ,Product_Code  
       ,Product_Business  
       ,Finance_Reporting_Product  
       ,SAM_Product  
       ,Distribution_Product  
       ,Source  
       ,'000000' as StaffNo_Num  
       ,'Unknown' as CMS_BranchName  
       ,0 as CMS_BranchID  
       ,0 as CMS_Branch  
       ,0 as Staff_Branch  
       ,'Unknown' as Staff_BranchName  
       ,0 as CMS_or_HR_Branch_firsttry  
       ,0 as NFP_Planner_Flag  
       ,'Unknown' as Position  
       ,'Unknown' as CMS_Area  
       ,'Unknown' as CMS_Region  
       ,'Unknown' as CMs_Brand  
       ,NULL as CMS_Active  
       ,NULL as CMS_StaffID  
       ,NULL as CMS_Staff_version_ID  
       ,0 as CMS_or_HR_Branch  
       ,'Unknown' as New_Sales_Channel  
       ,'Unknown' as Sales_Channel_L2  
       ,'Unknown' as Sales_Channel_L3  
       ,'Unknown' as Sales_Channel_L4  
       ,4010101 as Sales_Channel_source_ID  
       ,4 as Sales_Channel_ID  
       ,401 as Sales_Channel_L2_ID  
       ,40101 as Sales_Channel_L3_ID  
       ,4010101 as Sales_Channel_L4_ID  
       ,0 as Link_Nedbank_Staff  
   FROM
       [StagingDB].[dbo].[tmpmam6_missing]

USE [StagingDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tmpMam6_missing]
(
    [gPolicy_Number] [nvarchar](656) NULL,
    [gCustomer_Number] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [gProductkey] [int] NULL,
    [Policy_Number] [varchar](400) NULL,
    [Policy_Line_Active_Flag] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Policy_LIne_Open_Date] [date] NULL,
    [Policy_Line_Inactive_Date] [date] NULL,
    [Policy_Source] [varchar](400) NULL,
    [Lead_Source] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Planner_Banker] [varchar](400) NULL,
    [Planner_Banker_StaffNumber] [varchar](400) NULL,
    [StaffNo] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [Sales_Channel] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Policy_System_Status] [varchar](400) NULL,
    [Submit_Month] [int] NULL,
    [Accept_Month] [int] NULL,
    [Completed_Month] [int] NULL,
    [Lapse_Month] [nvarchar](6) NULL,
    [Surrender_Month] [nvarchar](6) NULL,
    [Reinstate_Month] [nvarchar](6) NULL,
    [Completed_Flag] [int] NULL,
    [Premium] [decimal](12, 2) NULL,
    [Frequency] [varchar](400) NULL,
    [Sales_Category] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Sales_SubCategory] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [HouseName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Cluster] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [segment_key] [int] NULL,
    [Dedupe_static] [numeric](20, 0) NULL,
    [Segment_Group] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Sement_Division] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Segment_L1_short_Desc] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Segment_L2_short_Desc] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Segment_L3_short_Desc] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Customer_type] [varchar](14) NULL,
    [Customer_Gender] [varchar](14) NULL,
    [Customer_DOB] [date] NULL,
    [ag_suburb_code] [varchar](13) NULL,
    [Micro_Market] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [RBB_Region] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [RBB_Province] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [RBB_Division] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Area_segment] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Product_roll_up] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Category] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Sub_Category] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Product_Code] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Product_Business] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Finance_Reporting_Product] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [SAM_Product] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Distribution_Product] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Source] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [StaffNo_Num] [varchar](6) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO


USE [StagingDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tmpMam6]
(
    [gPolicy_Number] [nvarchar](656) NULL,
    [gCustomer_Number] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [gProductkey] [int] NULL,
    [Policy_Number] [varchar](400) NULL,
    [Policy_Line_Active_Flag] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Policy_LIne_Open_Date] [date] NULL,
    [Policy_Line_Inactive_Date] [date] NULL,
    [Policy_Source] [varchar](400) NULL,
    [Lead_Source] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Planner_Banker] [varchar](400) NULL,
    [Planner_Banker_StaffNumber] [varchar](400) NULL,
    [StaffNo] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [Sales_Channel] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Policy_System_Status] [varchar](400) NULL,
    [Submit_Month] [int] NULL,
    [Accept_Month] [int] NULL,
    [Completed_Month] [int] NULL,
    [Lapse_Month] [nvarchar](6) NULL,
    [Surrender_Month] [nvarchar](6) NULL,
    [Reinstate_Month] [nvarchar](6) NULL,
    [Completed_Flag] [int] NULL,
    [Premium] [decimal](12, 2) NULL,
    [Frequency] [varchar](400) NULL,
    [Sales_Category] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Sales_SubCategory] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [HouseName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Cluster] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [segment_key] [int] NULL,
    [Dedupe_static] [numeric](20, 0) NULL,
    [Segment_Group] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Sement_Division] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Segment_L1_short_Desc] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Segment_L2_short_Desc] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Segment_L3_short_Desc] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Customer_type] [varchar](14) NULL,
    [Customer_Gender] [varchar](14) NULL,
    [Customer_DOB] [date] NULL,
    [ag_suburb_code] [varchar](13) NULL,
    [Micro_Market] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [RBB_Region] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [RBB_Province] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [RBB_Division] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Area_segment] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Product_roll_up] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Category] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Sub_Category] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Product_Code] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Product_Business] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Finance_Reporting_Product] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [SAM_Product] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Distribution_Product] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Source] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [StaffNo_Num] [varchar](6) NULL,
    [CMS_BranchName] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [CMS_BranchID] [int] NULL,
    [CMS_Branch] [int] NULL,
    [Staff_Branch] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Staff_BranchName] [char](50) NULL,
    [CMS_or_HR_Branch_firsttry] [int] NULL,
    [NFP_Planner_Flag] [int] NULL,
    [Position] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CMS_Area] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [CMS_Region] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [CMs_Brand] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [CMS_Active] [bit] NULL,
    [CMS_StaffID] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [CMS_Staff_version_ID] [int] NULL,
    [CMS_or_HR_Branch] [int] NULL,
    [New_Sales_Channel] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Sales_Channel_L2] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Sales_Channel_L3] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Sales_Channel_L4] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Sales_Channel_source_ID] [bigint] NULL,
    [Sales_Channel_ID] [bigint] NULL,
    [Sales_Channel_L2_ID] [bigint] NULL,
    [Sales_Channel_L3_ID] [bigint] NULL,
    [Sales_Channel_L4_ID] [bigint] NULL,
    [Link_Nedbank_Staff] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Sample data

```
INSERT INTO [StagingDB].[dbo].[tmpMam6] 
VALUES ('Bncs_P000009100000','121212121212','30238','P000009195843','0','2018-11-23','2019-08-26',NULL,'','','','','Independent Financial Advisors','CANCELLED','201811','201811','201812','190001','190001','190001','1','0.00','','UNK','UNK','UNK','UNK','3322','191271186706','Redbank','RBB','RBB','CB','Emerging MM','Individual','Male','1954-04-06','000766-017380','UITENHAGE / DISPATCH','PE & EAST LONDON','COASTAL BUSINESS UNIT','SOUTHERN','Emerging Market','Life','Credit Life','Personal Loans Credit Life','PLN','Personal Loan Assurance','Personal Loans Cover','Risk - Credit Life Individual Products','Personal Loans','TCS gfdsa','000000','Cape Team 2','992',NULL,NULL,NULL,'0',NULL,NULL,'Foreshore','Cape Region (CLOSED)','Personal Bank','0','000000','400','0','Face To Face','Face to Face Redbank','Product upsell','Product upsell','4010101','1','101','10111','1011101','0')

INSERT INTO [StagingDB].[dbo].[tmpMam6] 
VALUES ('Bncs_P000009111111','121212121212','30238','P000009195843','0','2018-11-23','2019-08-26',NULL,'','','','','Independent Financial Advisors','CANCELLED','201811','201811','201812','190001','190001','190001','1','0.00','','UNK','UNK','UNK','UNK','3322','191271186706','Redbank','RBB','RBB','CB','Emerging MM','Individual','Male','1954-04-06','000766-017380','UITENHAGE / DISPATCH','PE & EAST LONDON','COASTAL BUSINESS UNIT','SOUTHERN','Emerging Market','Life','Credit Life','Personal Loans Credit Life','PLN','Personal Loan Assurance','Personal Loans Cover','Risk - Credit Life Individual Products','Personal Loans','TCS jhgfd','000000','Cape Team 2','992',NULL,NULL,NULL,'0',NULL,NULL,'Foreshore','Cape Region (CLOSED)','Personal Bank','0','000000','400','0','Face To Face','Face to Face Redbank','Product upsell','Product upsell','4010101','1','101','10111','1011101','0')

INSERT INTO [StagingDB].[dbo].[tmpMam6] 
VALUES ('Bncs_P000009122222','121212121212','30238','P000009195843','0','2018-11-23','2019-08-26',NULL,'','','','','Independent Financial Advisors','CANCELLED','201811','201811','201812','190001','190001','190001','1','0.00','','UNK','UNK','UNK','UNK','3322','191271186706','Redbank','RBB','RBB','CB','Emerging MM','Individual','Male','1954-04-06','000766-017380','UITENHAGE / DISPATCH','PE & EAST LONDON','COASTAL BUSINESS UNIT','SOUTHERN','Emerging Market','Life','Credit Life','Personal Loans Credit Life','PLN','Personal Loan Assurance','Personal Loans Cover','Risk - Credit Life Individual Products','Personal Loans','TCS uytre','000000','Cape Team 2','992',NULL,NULL,NULL,'0',NULL,NULL,'Foreshore','Cape Region (CLOSED)','Personal Bank','0','000000','400','0','Face To Face','Face to Face Redbank','Product upsell','Product upsell','4010101','1','101','10111','1011101','0')

INSERT INTO [StagingDB].[dbo].[tmpMam6] 
VALUES ('Bncs_P000009133333','121212121212','30238','P000009195843','0','2018-11-23','2019-08-26',NULL,'','','','','Independent Financial Advisors','CANCELLED','201811','201811','201812','190001','190001','190001','1','0.00','','UNK','UNK','UNK','UNK','3322','191271186706','Redbank','RBB','RBB','CB','Emerging MM','Individual','Male','1954-04-06','000766-017380','UITENHAGE / DISPATCH','PE & EAST LONDON','COASTAL BUSINESS UNIT','SOUTHERN','Emerging Market','Life','Credit Life','Personal Loans Credit Life','PLN','Personal Loan Assurance','Personal Loans Cover','Risk - Credit Life Individual Products','Personal Loans','TCS iuytf','000000','Cape Team 2','992',NULL,NULL,NULL,'0',NULL,NULL,'Foreshore','Cape Region (CLOSED)','Personal Bank','0','000000','400','0','Face To Face','Face to Face Redbank','Product upsell','Product upsell','4010101','1','101','10111','1011101','0')

INSERT INTO [StagingDB].[dbo].[tmpMam6] 
VALUES ('Bncs_P000009144444','121212121212','30238','P000009195843','0','2018-11-23','2019-08-26',NULL,'','','','','Independent Financial Advisors','CANCELLED','201811','201811','201812','190001','190001','190001','1','0.00','','UNK','UNK','UNK','UNK','3322','191271186706','Redbank','RBB','RBB','CB','Emerging MM','Individual','Male','1954-04-06','000766-017380','UITENHAGE / DISPATCH','PE & EAST LONDON','COASTAL BUSINESS UNIT','SOUTHERN','Emerging Market','Life','Credit Life','Personal Loans Credit Life','PLN','Personal Loan Assurance','Personal Loans Cover','Risk - Credit Life Individual Products','Personal Loans','TCS lkjhg','000000','Cape Team 2','992',NULL,NULL,NULL,'0',NULL,NULL,'Foreshore','Cape Region (CLOSED)','Personal Bank','0','000000','400','0','Face To Face','Face to Face Redbank','Product upsell','Product upsell','4010101','1','101','10111','1011101','0')
```

```
INSERT INTO [StagingDB].[dbo].tmpMam6_missing 
VALUES ('Bncs_P000009100000','121212121212','30238','P000009195843','0','2018-11-23','2019-08-26',NULL,'','','','','Independent Financial Advisors','CANCELLED','201811','201811','201812','190001','190001','190001','1','0.00','','UNK','UNK','UNK','UNK','3322','191271186706','Redbank','RBB','RBB','CB','Emerging MM','Individual','Male','1954-04-06','000766-017380','UITENHAGE / DISPATCH','PE & EAST LONDON','COASTAL BUSINESS UNIT','SOUTHERN','Emerging Market','Life','Credit Life','Personal Loans Credit Life','PLN','Personal Loan Assurance','Personal Loans Cover','Risk - Credit Life Individual Products','Personal Loans','TCS gfdsa','000000')     

INSERT INTO [StagingDB].[dbo].tmpMam6_missing 
VALUES ('Bncs_P000009111111','121212121212','30238','P000009195843','0','2018-11-23','2019-08-26',NULL,'','','','','Independent Financial Advisors','CANCELLED','201811','201811','201812','190001','190001','190001','1','0.00','','UNK','UNK','UNK','UNK','3322','191271186706','Redbank','RBB','RBB','CB','Emerging MM','Individual','Male','1954-04-06','000766-017380','UITENHAGE / DISPATCH','PE & EAST LONDON','COASTAL BUSINESS UNIT','SOUTHERN','Emerging Market','Life','Credit Life','Personal Loans Credit Life','PLN','Personal Loan Assurance','Personal Loans Cover','Risk - Credit Life Individual Products','Personal Loans','TCS jhgfd','000000')     

INSERT INTO [StagingDB].[dbo].tmpMam6_missing 
VALUES ('Bncs_P000009122222','121212121212','30238','P000009195843','0','2018-11-23','2019-08-26',NULL,'','','','','Independent Financial Advisors','CANCELLED','201811','201811','201812','190001','190001','190001','1','0.00','','UNK','UNK','UNK','UNK','3322','191271186706','Redbank','RBB','RBB','CB','Emerging MM','Individual','Male','1954-04-06','000766-017380','UITENHAGE / DISPATCH','PE & EAST LONDON','COASTAL BUSINESS UNIT','SOUTHERN','Emerging Market','Life','Credit Life','Personal Loans Credit Life','PLN','Personal Loan Assurance','Personal Loans Cover','Risk - Credit Life Individual Products','Personal Loans','TCS uytre','000000')     

INSERT INTO [StagingDB].[dbo].tmpMam6_missing 
VALUES ('Bncs_P000009133333','121212121212','30238','P000009195843','0','2018-11-23','2019-08-26',NULL,'','','','','Independent Financial Advisors','CANCELLED','201811','201811','201812','190001','190001','190001','1','0.00','','UNK','UNK','UNK','UNK','3322','191271186706','Redbank','RBB','RBB','CB','Emerging MM','Individual','Male','1954-04-06','000766-017380','UITENHAGE / DISPATCH','PE & EAST LONDON','COASTAL BUSINESS UNIT','SOUTHERN','Emerging Market','Life','Credit Life','Personal Loans Credit Life','PLN','Personal Loan Assurance','Personal Loans Cover','Risk - Credit Life Individual Products','Personal Loans','TCS iuytf','000000')     

INSERT INTO [StagingDB].[dbo].tmpMam6_missing 
VALUES ('Bncs_P000009144444','121212121212','30238','P000009195843','0','2018-11-23','2019-08-26',NULL,'','','','','Independent Financial Advisors','CANCELLED','201811','201811','201812','190001','190001','190001','1','0.00','','UNK','UNK','UNK','UNK','3322','191271186706','Redbank','RBB','RBB','CB','Emerging MM','Individual','Male','1954-04-06','000766-017380','UITENHAGE / DISPATCH','PE & EAST LONDON','COASTAL BUSINESS UNIT','SOUTHERN','Emerging Market','Life','Credit Life','Personal Loans Credit Life','PLN','Personal Loan Assurance','Personal Loans Cover','Risk - Credit Life Individual Products','Personal Loans','TCS lkjhg','000000')
```

Comment: A process of elimination... you should know which columns are storing numeric values as a string (and you should avoid this if at all possible), so just comment them out one by one until you find it.

Comment: @DaleK, This is not his issue. His issue is the order of the columns in the SELECT which does not fit the order of the columns in the target, since he was lazy and did not explicitly wrote the columns in the INSERT part. Once he fix the order of one column in the SELECT, the INSERT will work well

Comment: @RonenAriely good for you for taking the time to investigate!

Comment: Did not took long time. I did what I wrote in my answer in order to find the problematic rows. I got that all the rows are bad which implies this issue, since it is very common issue, when people do not write the list of columns in the target table. Almost any company that I first come to consult have at least one lazy person who write poor code, and he is arguing that it's not important :-)

Comment: @RonenAriely because there is no sign of any research, and there are plenty of questions/resources out there which address this issue.

Comment: Given you're asking this question you're not on the latest release of SQL Server; SQL Server 2019 (at last) addresses this issue and *actually tells you*.

Answer (score 2):

This is the direct result of writing bad code and laziness!

If you try to write a good query which include (1) explicit `CONVERT` and (2) using the names of the columns in the target table, then this would not happen to you.

Your issue in this case is simply the order of columns in the `SELECT` statement, which does not fit the order of the columns in the target table.

Check the order of the columns in the target table. You will find that the column `[Premium]` comes before the column `[Frequency]`. But in your `SELECT` query the you first select the column `[Frequency]` and then the column `Premium`.

If you will change the order of the columns in the `SELECT` query then your `INSERT` will succeed fine.

To avoid such issues, as I mentioned in the beginning, you should NEVER count on the order of the columns in the target table! Always write the names in the `INSERT`!

```
INSERT INTO [StagingDB].[dbo].[tmpMam6] (<here you should use the list of columns in the order according to the SELECT>)
SELECT <use the same order of columns>
```

If you did this, then you probably would never had such issue

In addition, don't let the server to `CONVERT` the data type implicitly! Don't be lazy and always use `CONVERT` explicitly for each column which you need to change the type. In fact, you can even use `TRY_CONVERT` to avoid issues in converting the values (which in this case would not solve the order of the columns)

#### Back to your question which is not needed now but let's answer it

You can find issues in many ways like

1. You can use CURSOR and go row by row and mark the issues in the loop
2. You can use `ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT (INT, <column name here>),<use a numeric value which is out of the range you have in the production>)`. You can use this in a CTE and select all the rows with the "a numeric value which is out of the range you have in the production"

Answer (score -2):

Cast each column within the select statement to identify the type issue with data.
for example, SELECT 1 as INT, 1.21 AS NUMERIC(5,3),...

You can not use a single inverted comma with INTEGRE or NUMERIC value with data in the insert statement.